# Android: is it possible to disable/deactivate the standard Lock Screen?

Tags: android, lockscreen

I am trying to build a custom Lock Screen (or, I'd better say a kind of custom lock screen).

My question is the following: is it possible to disable/deactivate via code the standard Lock Screen of Android?

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: not without requesting root privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this would be possible, would be a huge security flaw in android and => fixed ASAP by Google and all companies!